# Utilizar variable o parámetro que esta en otro método

Tags: java

quiero llamar una variable de un `void` a otro `void` por ejemplo

```
public void void1(string datodeusuario){
}

public void void2(string fechausuario){
    system.out.printIn("hola"+datodeusuario) /////aquí es donde quiero llamar la variable pero no he podido

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como tienes tus métodos no es posible.

si lo que si te podría funcionar es poner una variable privada.

```
private string datodeusuario;

public void void1(string datodeusuario) {
  this.datodeusuarioombre = datodeusuario;
}

public void void2(string otroArgumento) {
  system.out.printIn("hola"+this.datodeusuario);
}
```

Con esto debería ser funcional lo que quieres hacer

Answer (score 5):

el problema que expones no me deja del todo claro el porqué quieres hacer algo como eso.

Hace mucho que no toco Java pero voy a tratar de ayudarte a entender por lo menos el porqué del error que te sale:

Según tengo entendido lo que quieres hacer no es posible, o por lo menos no de la forma en la que lo estás haciendo.

Esto es básicamente debido al "scope" o "ámbito" de las variables.
Cuando defines una variable dentro de un método, esa variable solo vivirá y podrá ser usada dentro del mismo método en el cual la has definido.

Por lo tanto:

```
public void metodo(string nombre) {
  // Este es el ámbito en el cual podrá ser usado el parámetro "nombre".
  // Solo dentro del código de las llaves de este método.
  system.out.println(nombre); // Bien !
}

public void metodo2(string otroArgumento) {
  // Acá el ámbito ha cambiado, por que es un método totalmente diferente.
  // Por lo tanto, si intentas llamar la variable "nombre" del método
  // anterior te arrojará un error.
  system.out.println(otroArgumento); // Bien!
  system.out.println(nombre); // Error, "nombre" no existe en este ámbito!
}
```

Sin embargo, se me ocurre que para lograr lo que quieres hacer bastaría con usar una variable global y estática a la que puedas acceder sin ningún problema; o la otra sería usar programación orientada a objetos, con herencia de clases, definiendo una clase padre que tenga su propiedad heredable y que la hija pueda acceder a ella, pero eso es algo un poco mas avanzado que seguro verás mas adelante.

Answer (score 2):

Considerando en la pregunta que los 2 métodos se encuentran en la misma clase, leer una variable de un método `void` dentro de otro método definido como `void`,  si te refieres a accederlos por el método, no es posible ya que un método `void` no regresa algún valor, lo que regularmente se realizar es declarar una variable de clase la cual pueda ser leída desde cualquier método:

```
private string datodeusuario;
```

de esta manera puedes obtener el valor en cualquiera de los métodos, recuerda también que ese valor lo podrías modificar en cualquier método de tu clase :

En este método asignas el valor:

```
public void void1(string datodeusuario){
  this.datodeusuario = "abcdefg12345";
}
```

En este otro puedes obtener el valor de la variable:

```
public void void2(string fechausuario){
    system.out.printIn("hola"+datodeusuario) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada, porqué el parámetro `fechausuario` lo tratas como string? Es preferible tratalo como `Date` y dentro del método formatearlo adecuadamente a string mediante `DateFormat`

Ej:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date)); //2013/10/15 16:16:39
```

Sobre tu pregunta, hay algo que te impida simplemente pasar la variable por parámetro al método `void2`?

```
public void void1(string datodeusuario){
          void2("11/09/2016", datodeusuario);
}

public void void2(string fechausuario, String datodeusuario){
    system.out.printIn("hola"+datodeusuario);

}
```